# Questions regarding itemize in Latex Beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

I am using Latex Beamer and I have questions with respect to itemize.

1. How is it possible to widen the space between the first level of itemize and the second one by means of a global statement? Furthermore, how is it possible to widen the space between the items of the second level?
2. How is it possible to align the position of the right arrow with the bullet? The position of the arrow is too far left.
3. How is it possible to adjust the two lines of the equation? Both should be aligned with the item "Example".

Here is an extract from my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode <presentation>{
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@listI}{\itemsep3\p@}{\itemsep1em}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{itemize}
\item Example (first level)
\begin{itemize}
\item Example (Item 1 of second level)
\item Example (Item 2 of second level)
\end{itemize}
\item[$\Rightarrow$] Example (right arrow)
\item Example (equation)
\begin{itemize}
\item Example
$\displaystyle\begin{aligned}[t] 
Z_{t} = \nu_{t} \sqrt{\alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1} Z_{t-1}^2} \text{ bei}   \alpha_{0}> 0 \text{ bzw. }  0<\alpha_{1}<1 \text{ und } \\ \nu_{t}\overset{uiv}{\sim}\textit{N}\text{(0,1)} \text{ sowie } \nu_{t} \text{ und } Z_{t-1} \text{ für alle t}\in \mathbb{Z} \text{ unabhängig voneinander}
\end{aligned}$ 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I provide the MWE in a proper format?

Comment: Use 4  single space before \begin{document} and so on...You can see the preview that is displayed below.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,83225.html#83225)

Answer (score 1):

For 1) You should use \vspace{1cm} between two successive itemize environments.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Delete the space between "<" and "presentation"
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@listI}{\itemsep3\p@}{\itemsep1em}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{itemize}
\item Example (first level)
\begin{itemize}
\item Example (Item 1 of second level)
\item Example (Item 2 of second level)
\end{itemize}
\vspace{1cm}
\item[$\Rightarrow$] Example (right arrow)
\item Example (equation)
\begin{itemize}
\item Example
$\displaystyle\begin{aligned}[t] 
Z_{t} = \nu_{t} \sqrt{\alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1} Z_{t-1}^2} \text{ bei}  \alpha_{0}> 0 \text{ bzw. }  0<\alpha_{1}<1 \text{ und } \\ \nu_{t}\overset{uiv}{\sim}\textit{N}\text{(0,1)} \text{ sowie } \nu_{t} \text{und  } Z_{t-1} \text{ für alle t}\in \mathbb{Z} \text{ unabhängig voneinander}
\end{aligned}$ 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]